# How to make a " homogeneous" gradient in glsl?

Tags: glsl, vulkan, vertex-shader

I don't know what is the best description for my target effect, but I want it to look this:
[image: Target]

I made these two attempts, where the color around diagonal line is more close to the right-down vertex.

[image]
[image]

```c
#version 450

layout(binding=0) uniform UniformBufferObject {
    mat4 model;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 proj;
} ubo;

layout(location=0) in vec2 inPosition;
layout(location=1) in vec3 inColor;
layout(location=2) in vec2 inUV;

layout(location=0) out vec3 fragColor;

vec3 azure = { 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f };
vec3 blue = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
vec3 green = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };

float translate(float i) {
    return i + 0.5;
}

float helpfunc(int x) {
    return mix(mix(blue[x], green[x], translate(inPosition.y)), mix(azure[x], azure[x], translate(inPosition.y)), translate(inPosition.x));
}

void main() {
    gl_Position = ubo.proj * ubo.view * ubo.model * vec4(inPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
    fragColor = vec3(helpfunc(0), helpfunc(1), helpfunc(2));
}
```

I thought that this might be leaded by the color space, yet since after exchanging the position of `blue` and `green` in function `helpfunc`, the color of the distinctive diagonal line changed, not the distinctive diagonal line postion. I guess the problem is in algorithm, but I can't figure out what it is or how to solve it.

Comment: cyan is (0,1,1), not (0,0.5,0.5)

Comment: In vertex sheder you should only assign the corner colors. Let the rasterizer do the interpolation via `smooth` perspective-aware interpolation.

Comment: I.e. should probably simply be `fragColor=inColor` in the vertex shader.

Comment: What if you do `fragColor=vec4(inPosition.x, inPosition.y, 0.0);` to make sure that inPosition is working properly?

Comment: thks krOoze, your solution works. i input the position data instead of color data, calculate it in frag shader, then got the smooth effect i want.

Comment: the `inPostion` is working properly i guess, it is working properly within locating the vertex.

Answer (score 1):

thks to krOoze, i find a way to solve my problem, since idk if it is the best solution.
the only thing i do is put the step "calculate the color" from vertex shader into frag shader.
here's my code:

```
//vertex shader
#version 450

layout(binding=0)uniform UniformBufferObject{
    mat4 model;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 proj;
    
}ubo;

layout(location=0)in vec2 inPosition;
layout(location=1)in vec3 inColor;
layout(location=2)in vec2 inUV;

layout(location=0)out vec2 outPosition;

void main(){
    gl_Position=ubo.proj*ubo.view*ubo.model*vec4(inPosition,0.,1.);
    outPosition=inPosition;
}
//frag shader
#version 450

layout(location=0)in vec2 outPosition;

layout(location=0)out vec4 outColor;

vec3 red={1.f,0.f,0.f};
vec3 blue={0.f,0.f,1.f};
vec3 green={0.f,1.f,0.f};
vec3 white={1.f,1.f,1.f};

float translate(float i){
    return i+.5;
}
float helpfunc(int x){
    return mix(mix(blue[x],green[x],translate(outPosition.y)),mix(white[x],red[x],translate(outPosition.y)),translate(outPosition.x));
}
void main(){
    outColor=vec4(helpfunc(0),helpfunc(1),helpfunc(2),1.);
}
```

and here is my outcome :
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f63RA.png]